# org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find setter for flat_rate on class dk.comtalk.billing.server.rating.db.RateDTO

Tags: hibernate

Got this exception while Transforming `SQL` result to `HQL`. `query.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(RateDTO.class)).list()`

but already i have setters and getters for the column `flat_rate` in `RateDTO` class

```
private BigDecimal flatRate;

    @Column(name="flat_rate")
public BigDecimal getFlatRate() {
    return flatRate;
}   

public void setFlatRate(BigDecimal flatRate) {
    this.flatRate = flatRate;
}
```

for corresponding table in `Mysql DB`. Can anyone please help me .

Comment: post your full stack trace. it might helpfull

Comment: actually im printing exception myself in log file, unable to print the complete stack trace. Tried but not to waste my time on it. Thanks for fast reply. can you give me any suggestions Pradeep.

Comment: provide your complete query code around this statement. query.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(RateDTO.class)).list()

Comment: Sorry for late reply, i didn't notice. Here is the query -- 

 final String sql =
                "select * " +
                "from international_rate r " +
                "WHERE LEFT(:called, LENGTH(r.prefix)) = r.prefix " + 
    "and r.valid_from <= :date AND ( r.Valid_to >= :date or r.Valid_to = 0)" + 
    "and r.deleted = 0";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [addScalar()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/api/org/hibernate/SQLQuery.html#addScalar%28java.lang.String,%20org.hibernate.type.Type%29) to query object before calling `query.list()`

```
final String sql = "select * " + "from international_rate r " + "WHERE LEFT(:called, LENGTH(r.prefix)) = r.prefix " + "and r.valid_from <= :date AND ( r.Valid_to >= :date or r.Valid_to = 0)" + "and r.deleted = 0"; "

    sess.createSQLQuery(sql)
     .addScalar("flatRate", Hibernate.STRING) //like all properties need to Add
.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(RateDTO.class)).list();
```

Comment: propertyName doesn't exist in my table.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `select student.name as name;` using `select *` will again throw exception. The alias names that you are using in the query should be same as the property names in your DTO class.